# What are the pros and cons of two different ways for implementing sections in UITableViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I need to download and parse some XML data, and to store it in sqlite. Then I need to present that data on table view. I'm trying to figure out the most effective way how to present that data further: take form sqlite and use it for table view that also uses a search. Therefore, I need to copy that data from the sqlite "source" into some "table data" property/ies in my table view controller. So, the two common ways are:

1. To have one NSArray property that contains section names (for example NSString type) and to have NSDictionary property (for storing rows) that keys are the section names contained in the first NSArray.
2. To have only one nested NSArray property (matrix): NSArray would contain elements that are also NSArrays, and each element in inner NSArray is a type of CustomClass of NSDictionary.
3. Other ways, please ....

I'm wondering what road should I take and what are pros and cons of those two (and maybe other) ways. Please share your experience and insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use Core Data to store your data? It uses sqlite as the back-end if the store type of the NSPeristentStoreCoordinator is NSSQLiteStoreType. If you are not familiar with it, make a new project, tick Use Core Data on creation. You will need to spend some time to learn it, but it is worth it. It's all there, storing, searching, filtering, sorting, displaying in a table view, etc.

Comment: Yes, indeed it's another way (+1). Speaking of my situation, hm..., I'm thinking of Core Data as heavyweight framework that adds unnecessary complexity and performance slowdown because I'm dealing with a small amount of data (less than 200 records)

Comment: OK, this does make sense. In this case I would use the option #3. Array of sections, each section is a class that contains properties, like the name, etc. and array of rows. A row is a class with certain properties. The section and the row classes should implement NSCoding, so you can serialise the whole array with NSKeyedArchiver, save it to the file and restore. You could also choose to use a dictionary for a row, but you would have more hassles with it then with a custom class. IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the thoughts :) Your proposal is close to my #2 option because it's about nesting sections and rows, and this approach looks for me more clear than having two different arrays. Just asked that because I saw some posts on internet that propose to use #1 option.